# pre_get_posts returns non property object when using posts__not_in

Tags: pre-get-posts

I'm displaying posts from a category and want to show all but the first one using posts__not_in. The code below is returning a property of non object error.

```
function modify_onthisday_cat( $query ) {

    if ($query->is_category(7) && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        global $post, $wp_query;

        set_query_var( 'day', date('d') );
        set_query_var( 'post__not_in', array($post->ID) );

        return;
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'modify_onthisday_cat');
```

If I replace $post->ID with a specific post id, it will work, but I need it to be dynamic. From what I understand this action is ran before the query so getting that id dynamically is going to take some more work. I'm just not sure how to get there.

Edit (clarification):

Currently, I have a category page served up with the category.php template. I have a featured post displayed above and the remaining posts displayed below. The featured post is called from a custom function and the remaining posts are called from the default wordpress loop.

My goal is to show the posts below while not showing the first post and preserving pagination.

Comment: You want to exclude the first posts from that category page ? And while filtering the main query, this is logical that the `$post` will not be available. What is the goal actually ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `pre_get_posts` incorrectly.

1. You should not be `return`ing anything at all
2. And you should be manipulating the query object that is passed into the filter and not modifying the globals at all.

For example:

```
function modify_onthisday_cat( $query ) {
  if ($query->is_category(7) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    global $post; // not going to be set yet
    $query->set( 'day', date('d') );
    $query->set( 'post__not_in', array($post->ID) ); // and this will fail
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'modify_onthisday_cat');
```

As noted in a comment, though, this won't work for the main query (and you seem to intend it for such), since `$post` won't be populated until after the main query runs-- that is what determines the value(s) in `$post`. I think you are going to have to explain your goal in more detail.

Something like the following should work better for single post pages, at least.

```
function modify_onthisday_cat( $query ) {
  $post_id = get_query_var('p');
  if ($query->is_category(7) && $query->is_main_query() && !empty($post_id)) {
    $query->set( 'day', date('d') );
    $query->set( 'post__not_in', array($post_id) );
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'modify_onthisday_cat');
```

Comment: Turns out I was over thinking it. A simple
`set_query_var( 'offset', 1 );` did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: @certainstrings Then please mark the answer as solution by ticking the checkmark below the voting arrows on the left hand side of this question

Comment: @certainstrings: I am not convinced that manipulating `offset` is a reliable fix.

Comment: You are correct. It disables category pagination when doing so. I'll have to troubleshoot another fix.